# Jetbrain clion include <fstream> failed

Tags: c++, clion

I am editing others codes from github and I import the codes with Jetbrain CLion.

When I include  or , it says file not found.

```
fatal error: fstream: No such file or directory
```

But it works when I open a new project.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide full error message?

Comment: Did you specify the type of the project?

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher I did not specify the type of project I just import it in jetbrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment you gave, the issue is that CLion doesn't know the type of project you have.

If you don't specify that it's C++, it will use a default type, and it won't be able to build it.